# How can I return a value from a retrofit response?

Tags: android, kotlin, request, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a retrofit request and return the value from the response but I don't know how to do that. Inside the onReponse function my list contains the right values, but when I'm trying to return it, the list is empty.

Here is my function:

```
 fun getFinancialDetailsService(mandatorGuid: String): List<FinancialDetails.FinancialDetailsItem> {
    val mandatorItem = MandatorItem(mandatorGuid)
    val guid: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    guid["guid"] = mandatorItem.guid


    val call: Call<FinancialDetails> = createAPI().getFinancialDetails(mandatorItem.guid)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<FinancialDetails> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<FinancialDetails>, t: Throwable) {
            
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<FinancialDetails>, response: Response<FinancialDetails>) 
            financialDetailsData = response.body()!!.data
            Log.i("TEST", "Financial Response: " + financialDetailsData.toString())
        }

    })
    Log.i("TEST", "Financial RETURN " + call.execute().body()!!.data.toString())
    return financialDetailsData
}
```

If you have any solution please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: I can't really understand how it works..

Answer (score 0):

May be because return financialDetailsData Before onResponse is called